# Cannot launch a Python application due to module python-socks not being found after I just installed it

Tags: python

first I want to emphasize the fact that I have little to no experience with Python and that I've already tried searching for the solution online, but I haven't found anything that would even be close to answering my questions. Python is something I will surely delve into, but I want to ask this question to not wait weeks, or maybe months, for it to happen since I just want to launch a Python application at this point

When I attempt to launch a Python application through CMD, it cannot find the module "python-socks":

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_socks'
```

I installed python-socks, through the

```
pip install python-socks
```

command.

When I attempt to install it again, I am given the communicate:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-socks in PATH
```

The execution path should technically be automatically adjusted due to my Python installation settings and I checked python-socks "site" to see if I am maybe installing it wrong, but this aspect seems to be fine

All the answers I find online seem to assume that the problem was this command not being used at all and that after it is used, everything should be fine. It isn't. I have Python 3.9.5 installed and it's temporary since the same command does not want to execute on Python 3.11.5 either and it's a remnant of my earlier attempts at solving the problem. Yes, I've tried telling Python which version to use too, but I wanted to eliminate potential causes

As I said, Python is something that I am yet to explore, at this point I am basically a novice, or maybe even worse, so please be understanding while potentially answering the question. I just figured out that this issue might be something really easy to solve for experienced users, so I can ask. I will, of course, provide more details, if necessary to solve the issue

Thank you, in advance, to anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what's wrong in general

Comment: never used this library, but you seem to install `python-socks` (hyphen) and import `python_socks` (underscore).  Is this the change in the naming how is supposed to be?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I apologise: Both version have been tried and the result seems to be the same

Comment: can you try `python -m pip install python-socks` ?

Comment: Check out [docs](https://pypi.org/project/python-socks), it seems `python_socks` have submodules which can only be imported

Comment: What do you use for launching your python script ? If you user `python script.py`, what does `python -m pip install python-socks` outputs ? maybe your pip command doesn't reference to the same python

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The result of this command is:
'Requirement already satisfied: python-socks in  PATH'

Comment: @Ant0ine64 The result is: 

'Requirement already satisfied: python-socks in PATH'

Comment: @adityanithariya Alright, I will check it and inform about the results of my search

Comment: @adityanithariya I am not knowledgeable in the matter, so I installed all of these optional submodules and the result of me trying to launch the application after this is the same, so:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_socks'

Comment: Which application are you running?

Comment: @adityanithariya Eh... I won't hide the fact that it's a bit of a private matter and I do realise that it may be detrimental to the possibility of answering the question, but it's really something I would rather not make known publicly. I really hope you understand and I apologise if it comes off as rude, as it is not my intention in the slightest

Is it possible that the application itself is at fault in such a type of an issue, so the module not being found? Genuine question

Comment: Then you should consider asking the maintainers of the application to resolve this issue, because if you're not able to disclose your problem, stackoverflow is not the right place for you and this question as well

Comment: @adityanithariya It is sadly not possible, it was the last resort. Well, not bad to try. If it's not possible, then I will live with it, but at this point, I just want to know what I am doing wrong. Anyway, if lack of information about what application it is, makes the answer impossible then I can just send my regards and thank everyone who have attempted to tell the novice what might be the problem

Comment: I tried installing `python_socks` and importing it, it works completely fine

Comment: This issue must be of path

Comment: @adityanithariya Hm, I will explore this possibility later for sure. Now I need to go, but I will go back to it, to not make anyone feel that their suggestions and advice were ignored and/or disregarded because they are not